# Connect 2 different containers to the same mongoDB container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 nodejs containers running each one a different app and I want to connect them to the same mongoDB.

Each one works well alone together it won't let me have multiple connections for the same container.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app-dpp:
    container_name: preProcessing-Docker
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "/preProcessing-Docker/Dockerfile-dpp"
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    links:
      - mongo

  app-df:
    container_name: dataFusion-Docker
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "dataFusion-docker/Dockerfile-df"
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    links:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
    - data-volume:/data/db   
volumes:
  data-volume:
```

I have been getting this error:

```
"ERROR: for app-dpp  Cannot create container for service app-dpp: Conflict. The container name "/preProcessing-Docker" is already in use by container "cc01c6f8189a50f95438309860dcb959232c7da4606054ec9d79b9340a532398". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name."
```

I would like to have the same DB since it would be better to share the db between the two modules than to have two dbs.

Comment: Looks like you already have a container named "preProcessing-Docker" on your machine. There cannot exist 2 containers by same name at the same time.

Comment: Did you try deleting the previously existing container? Does it work now?

Comment: If I run docker ps the container list is empty. preProcessing-Docker is the first container I launch, the second one is dataFusion-Docker.

Comment: type `docker container ls -a` and you'll see the container by that name.

Comment: `docker ps -a`  will show *all* containers (default without `-a` shows just _running_ containers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a container by the name `preProcessing-Docker`. Because docker cannot allow you to have multiple containers by the same name, it won't work.

Type `docker container ls -a` to list all of your containers and delete the one that exists by that name and `docker-compose up` later and it should work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, you were right there were some containeres that weren't running with that name and dataFusion-Docker. Thanks for the help.